# SQL Query, "[...] WHERE field IS NOT NULL" shows 'field' with NULL values

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: IS NOT NULL shows NULL values]

I must be doing something wrong, or I don't understand the "IS NOT NULL" part, should it be showing me rows with NULL columns that I specifically wanted to no be NULL?

Comment: Can you copy and paste that section of code also please, it's difficult to read.

Comment: Boolean logic for 2 simultaneous negatives needs OR not AND.Change AND to OR and put the 2 conditions in parenthesis.

Comment: You have the `column IS NOT NULL` condition in the `LEFT` join `ON` clause, not in the `WHERE`, that's why.

Comment: -1 for pasting an illegible screenshot.

Comment: I just uploaded it via SO's available tools, the original I have saved on my computer is more than good enough to read.

Comment: Post code, not images.

Comment: Thought it would be easier to show the results I got and the sql in a single view, with highlights for clarity, no need for a public lynching.

Comment: Where is the lynching? People have been trying to help you. Why haven't you edited the question yet, removing the image and posting code?

Comment: This particular question is solved(when I try to mark an answer as accepted I get "You can post in 2 minutes", which doesn't make much sense), however it brought up another question, I don't know whether to make a new post or do it all through here.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing a `left outer join` on `guesses`. When the condition in the `on` is `false`, no row will be returned for that `join` and the fields referenced from that table will be `null`.

You have a few options I think, all depending on your needs:

- Put this condition in the `where` clause;
- Don't use the `left outer join`, but just a regular `join`;
- Use `coalesce` to default the values.

Comment: It has to be a Left join because not all games by not all users have guesses associated with them, the where clause solved it, thank you very much.

Comment: @AmandoFilipe: No problem. If your question was answered, please don't forget to vote / accept the answer you deem most helpful.

Comment: It brought me to another question, yes, but it's pretty complex and kind of long.

Comment: @DoYouEvenLift: Okay, but if this question was resolved, please accept (any) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try use the below constructed query

```
select * from Tbl_EmployeeDetails where  (name is not NULL or name <> 'null')
```

Comment: This doesn't help since it doesn't address the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Just user regular join instead of left outer join :

```
SELECT guesses.*, games.* FROM games,guesses 
WHERE guesses.game_id = games.game_id 
AND games.real_score_team_1 IS NOT NULL AND games.real_score_team_2 IS NOT NULL ;
```

That should do the trick

Comment: @PatrickHofman That was in a comment only. The question should be edited for clarification. We do not have to go through all the various comments.

Comment: @ypercube: I know, but since the answer was already downvoted by others (not me) the answerer was maybe waiting on feedback from OP.

Comment: What's a "regular join" ?